# asp.net mvc 2 custom controller factory

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm learning MVC in the asp.net space. If I want to pass my controller ctor a parameter it seems like I can create a controller factory that I register with the MVC framework. I see examples like below and I have to wonder how the MVC framework knows to use this factory when a controller is created?

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    public IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
       {
        ILogger logger = new DefaultLogger();
        var controller = new HomeController(logger);
        return controller;
    }
    public System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(
   System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        return SessionStateBehavior.Default;
    }
    public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        IDisposable disposable = controller as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
            disposable.Dispose();
    }
} 

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
    RegisterCustomControllerFactory ();
    }
}
private void RegisterCustomControllerFactory ()
{
    IControllerFactory factory = new CustomControllerFactory();
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);
}
```

So this controller factory creates an instance of the HomeController and passes a specific Logger object. Is the default controller factory never used in this application now because of registering this custom controller factory? Do I have 2 factories now? The default for all other controllers and this specific one just for the HomeController? If so how does MVC know which controller factory to use? In an application I would want many controllers all taking different parameter types, so how would that work?

I tried googling this specific question but couldn't really find anything around it. I just found a bunch of frameworks people use, but I want to understand this specific part of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need controller factory for that. Take a look at [asp.net mvc dependency injection](https://www.google.ge/search?q=asp.net%20mvc%20dependency%20injection&oq=asp.net%20mvc%20dependency%20injection&gs_l=serp.3...21643.21869.0.21965.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.19.serp.uv1SUQsl4bQ). You should get the basic overview, and than find dependency injector able to work with asp.net mvc 2

Comment: What if I don't want to use a 3rd party dependency injector framework? It seems making custom controllers is the way to go then right? If so my question stands. It seems like almost every resonably complex MVC app would need this functionality, so why have all these external dependency injectors instead of having something built-in?

Comment: Also, looking at http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/07/tdd-and-dependency-injection-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx it still creates a custom controller factory, but again I don't see the link on how MVC knows that this controller uses this custom type in it's ctor. I don't seem to see anything explicitly defined.